# Column recoding based on count of distincts

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I've a panda data frame like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'VAR1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A','B', 'B'],

'VAR2': ['C', 'V', 'C', 'C','V', 'D']}

frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Fundamentally I need to recode each variable. The recoding would work like this: calculate a count of distinct values for each column, and if the count is greater than or equal to a threshold, keep the original value, otherwise set a new value of 'X'. If the threshold were 3, then this is what it would need to look like.

```
data2 = {'VAR3': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A','X', 'X'],

'VAR4': ['C', 'X', 'C', 'C','X', 'X']}

frame2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

And this is the desired output, with the original data merged to the recoded data.

```
pd.merge(frame, frame2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

I'm new to Python and while the book Python for Data Analysis is really helping me, I still cannot quite figure out how to achieve the desired result in a simple way.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take each column individually. Group it by value, and use the `filter` method on groups to replace any group with less than 3 values with `NaN`. Then replace those `NaNs` with `X`.

You could do this all in one list comprehension, but for clarity I defined a `recode` function that does all the substantial stuff.

```
In [38]: def recode(s, threshold):
   ....:     return s.groupby(s).filter(lambda x: x.count() >= threshold, dropna=False).fillna(value='X')
   ....:
```

Applying to each column and then reassembling the columns into one new DataFrame....

```
In [39]: frame2 = pd.concat([recode(frame[col], 3) for col in frame], axis=1)

In [40]: frame2
Out[40]: 
  VAR1 VAR2
0    A    C
1    A    X
2    A    C
3    A    C
4    X    X
5    X    X
```

And, to be sure, you can merge the original and the recoded frames just as you expressed it in your question:

```
In [27]: pd.merge(frame, frame2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
Out[27]: 
  VAR1_x VAR2_x VAR1_y VAR2_y
0      A      C      A      C
1      A      V      A      X
2      A      C      A      C
3      A      C      A      C
4      B      V      X      X
5      B      D      X      X
```

**Edit:** Use this equivalent workaround for pandas version < 0.12:

```
def recode(s, threshold):
    b = s.groupby(s).transform(lambda x: x.count() >= threshold).astype('bool') # True/False
    s[~b] = 'X'
    return s
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. When I try to run it, it gives me an error: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'filter'

Comment: ``filter`` is a new feature, and it did not realize it is not available in the latest stable release, only on the developer version so far. It will come out in a couple weeks. Meanwhile, see my edit for a workaround.